# How to assign a number for ever unique element?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like -

```
No.     Alphabet
 1.       A
 2.       B
 3.       A
 4.       A
 5.       C                 
 6.       B
 7.       C
```

Now, I want to add a new column outcome which would give a new number to every unique element. So the final table would be

```
No.     Alphabet   Outcome
 1.       A           1
 2.       B           2
 3.       A           1
 4.       A           1    
 5.       C           3                     
 6.       B           2 
 7.       C           3
```

How can I achieve that with R?

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? It's possible that you're doing this as an intermediate step in something and you might be able to skip it entirely if we know what you're really trying to do.

Comment: @Dason I want to apply KNN algo to this. This is not exactly my data frame, but I have recreated it to make it simple. As KNN does not accept character inputs, I need to convert these variables into numbers and now I can apply KNN on it.

Comment: Which function from which package are you using for knn?

Comment: function knn from class package.

Comment: I believe if you store it as factor instead of character (and in this case it really probably should be a factor anyways) that you don't need to do an explicit conversion to numeric.  This would be the better approach to take.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `as.numeric(factor(.))`, like this:

```
> Letter <- c("A", "A", "B", "C", "B", "A")
> as.numeric(factor(Letter))
[1] 1 1 2 3 2 1
```

Assigning as a column can be done using the standard `mydf$outcome <- etc` or your favorite/preferred approach.

Comment: Mine's faster =P (+1)

Comment: @BrodieG, don't make me whip out `fmatch` now....

Answer (score 4):

You could also do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Outcome:= .GRP, Alphabet][]
#    No. Alphabet Outcome
#1:   1        A       1
#2:   2        B       2
#3:   3        A       1
#4:   4        A       1
#5:   5        C       3
#6:   6        B       2
#7:   7        C       3
```

#### Benchmarks

```
library(fastmatch)
set.seed(24)
df2 <- data.frame(No = 1:1e7, Alphabet= sample(LETTERS, 1e7, 
            replace=TRUE), stingsAsFactors=FALSE)
df3 <- copy(df2)
Ananda <- function() {transform(df2, 
             outcome = as.numeric(factor(df2$Alphabet)))}
Brodie <- function() {transform(df2, outcome=match(Alphabet, Alphabet))}
Brodie2 <- function(){transform(df2, outcome=fmatch(Alphabet, Alphabet))}

akrun <- function() {setDT(df3)[, Outcome:= .GRP, Alphabet][]}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(Ananda(), Brodie(), Brodie2(), akrun(), 
                    unit='relative', times=20L)
# Unit: relative
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
# Ananda() 4.957064 5.150724 4.427514 4.971581 3.336064 4.622502    20   c
# Brodie() 4.473689 5.074105 4.838985 5.383722 4.641304 4.383919    20   c
#Brodie2() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    20 a  
#  akrun() 1.609863 2.047646 1.665557 1.949590 1.331554 1.290921    20  b 


 system.time(akrun())
 #  user  system elapsed 
 # 0.197   0.005   0.202 

 system.time(Brodie2())
 #  user  system elapsed 
 # 0.081   0.014   0.095
```

Comment: Thanks for running through all the benchmarks, very helpful (+1, though you got that a while ago).

Answer (score 3):

Another option (for fun) using `match`:

```
match(Alphabet, Alphabet)
```

`match` only matches the first occurrence, so this works, though the numbers will not be 1:26.  If they must absolutely be 1:26, and not just unique:

```
match(Alphabet, unique(Alphabet))
```

To actually do what you want (adding a column in data frame, etc.):

```
transform(DF, outcome=match(Alphabet, Alphabet))
```

Or

```
transform(DF, outcome=match(Alphabet, unique(Alphabet)))
```

Or you can use a faster version of `match` ie. `fmatch` from `library(fastmatch)`

```
library(fastmatch)
transform(DF, outcome=fmatch(Alphabet, unique(Alphabet)))
#  No. Alphabet outcome
#1   1        A       1
#2   2        B       2
#3   3        A       1
#4   4        A       1
#5   5        C       3
#6   6        B       2
#7   7        C       3
```

This is actually a little faster than the `factor` version:

```
> x <- sample(letters, 1e5, rep=T)
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(as.numeric(factor(x)), match(x, x))
Unit: milliseconds
                  expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 as.numeric(factor(x)) 4.68927 4.792212 9.042732 4.915268 5.175275 64.65473   100
           match(x, x) 3.55855 3.617609 6.981944 3.731522 3.922048 53.07911   100
```

most likely because `factor` internally uses something like `match(x, unique(x))` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your data frame is called `dat`. Then you can do

```
dat$Outcome <- as.numeric(as.factor(dat$Alphabet))
```